# Abstract format in a game studies conference

Tags: paper-submission, abstract, conference

I will submit an "extended abstract" to a conference in game studies. This is not my primary field of study (more of a hobby), so the stakes are low and I am unaware of the conventions of the field. It is also a reasonably new field of study, so it is not clear how standardized any conventions are.

The guidelines for the abstract submission are as follows:

> The papers to be presented will be chosen based on extended abstract review. 
>   The abstracts should be 500–1000 words (plus references). Abstracts should be 
>   delivered in PDF format. Please use 12 pt Times New Roman, double-spaced, for 
>   your text.

The description leaves some questions open.

- Presumably I should add the title of the abstract/talk to the submission.
- There is no mention of whether the peer review will be double-blind or not, and consequently whether I should include my name or not.
- Is there a standard citation style within the field?

This is the first time this particular conference has an academic track, so it is not possible to consider earlier iterations of it. The conference in question is the academic track of Ropecon 2018.